# how to reinstall bash on Mac High Sierra (10.13.6) The current bash just does not work

Tags: bash, macos-highsierra

On bash all these commands generates the same message which is "command not found".

Here is the recent session from my terminal:

```
bash --version > -bash: bash: command not found
ls /usr/local/bin/ > -bash: ls: command not found
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you edit your ~/.bashrc recently? What do you see with `echo "$PATH"`? To get back on track while you're figuring out what happened, do `PATH=$(getconf PATH)`

Comment: This is an XY Problem. You really need to fix your PATH environment variable. Reinstalling bash won't fix a broken PATH.

Comment: @glennjackman. Thanks for your valuable inputs. I have managed to fix my .bash_profile now and every this is back to normal!!

Comment: @Spiff, yes the PATH was broken indeed which I have now fixed.

Comment: @Singam Excellent! The thing to do now for this Question is to post your own Answer on how you fixed it, and then accept your own Answer by clicking the checkmark outline next to it. This will mark your issue as resolved, so others with the same question will find your solution in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my .bash_profile on Mac and there was a syntax error that was corrupting the whole thing.
From

```
export PATH="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:$PATH'
```

To

```
export PATH="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:$PATH"
```

The PATH value now begins with a double quote and ends with a double quote as well, whereas earlier, it ended with the single quote.